# What is the difference between "going to" and "going to be"?

Tags: passive-voice, gerunds, infinitives, future, active-voice

What is the difference between two sentences:

1. Are you going to be filling the bird feeder soon?
2. Are you going to fill the bird feeder soon?

Is this something to do with active and passive voice?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/546439/how-can-i-understand-the-sentence-1b/546441#546441

Comment: This is not about _going to_. The same difference shows up in _Are you filling them soon?_ and _Do you fill them soon?_ As @ColinFine points out, this is the difference between using the Continuous construction (aka the Progressive or the _-ing_ construction) and not using it.  This is very basic and is not a tense, nor a voice.

Answer (score 4):

Not active and passive, rather (so-called) simple and continuous.

*To be filling* is an infinitive form that corresponds to *am/are/is filling*, just as *to fill* is an infinitive form that corresponds to *fill/fills**.

As to the difference in meaning: it's very slight, and mostly to do with attitude.

*Are you going to fill the bird feeder soon?*

is neutral - it could of course be said with various tones of voice, but the choice of words does not convey any attitude.

*Are you going to be filling the bird feeder soon?*

has a more tentative feel: perhaps something like "Is it already in the list of things you are planning to do to fill the bird feeder?" It might be said to to make the question sound less like a command (though not necessarily:  it could be said with an angry or impatient voice).

*This is why some modern grammarians don't like to talk about the "be -ing" form as a *tense*: it's one of several verbal constructions in English that can be combined with other constructions such as *would/will/may/could etc*, *be -ed*, *have -en*, *be going to*.